# av_guess_format h264 returns NULL on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264

executing this code:

```
av_log_set_callback(_log_callback);
av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();
LOG(avcodec_configuration());
AVOutputFormat * fmt = av_guess_format( "h264", NULL, NULL );
```

And showing in my log file the next configuration:

```
 --target-os=linux --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avfilter --disable-everything --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-gpl ....
```

`av_guess_format` is returning NULL.

Any suggestion?
many thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try to list all registered codecs:

```
AVCodec * codec = NULL;
while(codec = av_codec_next(codec))
{
    LOG(codec->name);
}
```

**UPD**

You can create an encoder for H264:

```
AVCodec * avCodec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264");
AVCodecContext * avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);
// fill all required fields in avCodecCtx
AVDictionary * opt = NULL;
avcodec_open2(avCodecCtx, avCodec, &opt);
```

You do not have any formats, because you specified option `--disable-everything`

Comment: h264, vp8, libvpx, libx264 were listed.

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to me that you are creating an encoder. You want to create a container for RAW H264?

Comment: I am encoding video with h264. On windows ffmpeg+h264 is working fine, then I want to run the same app on android.

Comment: You have specified the option `--disable-everything`. You have not registered formats, only specified video codecs.

Comment: I have made a quickly test and without --disable-everything is working :). but libavcodec.a is huge! +1 for seeing the flag, when I check your answer I will validate it ;)

Comment: You can leave this flag and specify separately required parts `--enable-demuxer=... --enable-protocol=... --enable-muxer=...`